# The difference between system and light theme?

Tags: flutter

I try to use `theme_mode_handler` plugin to change a theme of an app. What is the difference between `system` theme and `light` theme? The `primaryColor` defined in `theme` applies to both of them...

```
return MaterialApp(
  themeMode: themeMode,
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  ),
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Colors.lightGreen, // this applies to the light and system theme
  ),
  home: HomePage(),
);
```

So how to diffrentiate setting primary color between them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System theme depends on theme of device. If the device has light theme selecting system theme will apply light theme to your application and if the device has dark theme your application will be using dark theme.

Whereas light/dark theme directly resembles to its name.